# How to use a:hover

Tags: html, css

**UPDATE:

```css
#tablaarriba a:hover {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table style="text-align: left; width: 1113px; height: 123px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><br>
        <div style="text-align: left;"><a href="home.htm"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 240px; height: 95px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Logo/logo_rosy.jpg" alt="RosyGLogo"></a></div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="tablaarriba">
          <a style="color: black; text-decoration: none; background-color: transparent;" href="social.htm">Social</a><br>
          </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
        <br>
        <br>
  </div>
    <a style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" href="file:///Users/monmunoz/Desktop/Colegio/Tec/Quinto%20Semestre/ITGS/PROYECTO/Comercial.htm">Comercial</a><br>
  </td>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" href="proyectospersonales.htm">Proyectos Personales</a><br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" href="sobrelafotografa.htm">Sobre la fotógrafa</a><br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" href="contacto.htm">Contacto</a><br>
</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="20">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><img style="width: 367px; height: 244px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_1647.jpg" alt="DSC_1647.jpg"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><img style="width: 244px; height: 367px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3043.jpg" alt="DSC_3043.jpg"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><img style="width: 367px; height: 245px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3813.jpg" alt="DSC_3813.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><img style="width: 244px; height: 367px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3074.jpg" alt="DSC_3074.jpg"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><img style="width: 367px; height: 245px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3817.jpg" alt="DSC_3817.jpg"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><img style="width: 244px; height: 367px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3077.jpg" alt="DSC_3077.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div data-role="footer">
  <div style="text-align: center;"> <small><span style="font-family: Century Gothic;">Rosy G. Photography ©</span></small><br>
  </div>
  <h1 style="text-align: center;"><br>
  </h1>
</div>
```

** **I changed some details in the html pointed out by the HTML validator. So now I have this.**
I'm almost done building my website; however I'm trying to incorporate the a:hover attribute in my stylesheet and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I want my links to change to color grey whenever the mouse passes above them. Please help me. So far I have this:

Comment: Your div tag for `<div id="tablaarriba"` is not closed in your markup. Is that an issue on your machine as well?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I already fixed it and it's still not showing the hover effect.

Comment: Few things to start with: 1. Validate your html and CSS, and if any errors arise, try fixing or let us know (google 'html and css validator'). 2. Add a JSfiddle. 3. what happens, what do you want to happen, what did you try? 4. [mcve]

Comment: That's your homework. Tag me when you are done. :)

Comment: See my answer, I don't think CSS uses grey but instead uses gray. Though grey is the correct spelling in some countries.

Comment: actually both grey and gray are supported: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/ (4.3)

Comment: I added a second part to my answer. See how I moved the html from inside your page to the separate css file and it started working? I just did the first 2 tags. You'll want to go through and move everything yourself but that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#tablaarriba a:hover {
  color: gray ;
}
```

```html
<div id="tablaarriba">
  <a href="#">LINK</a>
</div>
```

```css
table a:hover {
  color: gray ;
}

table a {
  color: black; text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>

  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<link href="menuarriba.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Rosy G Photography and Artwork</title>


</head><body>
<table style="text-align: left; width: 1113px; height: 123px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><br>
      <div style="text-align: left;"><a href="home.htm"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 240px; height: 95px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Logo/logo_rosy.jpg" alt="RosyGLogo"></a></div>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="tablaarriba">
      <a href="social.htm">Social</a><br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      </div>
      <a href="file:///Users/monmunoz/Desktop/Colegio/Tec/Quinto%20Semestre/ITGS/PROYECTO/Comercial.htm">Comercial</a><br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <a href="proyectospersonales.htm">Proyectos Personales</a><br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <a href="sobrelafotografa.htm">Sobre la fotógrafa</a><br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Century Gothic; color: black;"><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <a style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" href="contacto.htm">Contacto</a><br>
      </td>
      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="20">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><img style="width: 367px; height: 244px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_1647.jpg" alt="DSC_1647.jpg"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><img style="width: 244px; height: 367px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3043.jpg" alt="DSC_3043.jpg"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><img style="width: 367px; height: 245px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3813.jpg" alt="DSC_3813.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><img style="width: 244px; height: 367px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3074.jpg" alt="DSC_3074.jpg"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><img style="width: 367px; height: 245px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3817.jpg" alt="DSC_3817.jpg"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><img style="width: 244px; height: 367px;" src="Fotos%20ITGS/Comercial/DSC_3077.jpg" alt="DSC_3077.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div data-role="footer">
<div style="text-align: center;"> <small><span style="font-family: Century Gothic;">Rosy G. Photography ©</span></small><br>
</div>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><br>
</h1>
</div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: I also tried this answer and I still don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @MonseMunoz when you hit 'Run code snippet' does that work in your browser?

Comment: @Moonsemunoz if you are hitting that button and it works here but not on your site. It's likely that something else is overriding the css. Try putting that bit of CSS at the very bottom of your css file.

Comment: @MontseMunoz put it at the very bottom of menuarriba.css if you currently have it at the top. Then let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: The thing is that's all I have for css. I edited all the page with html.

Comment: @MontseMunoz it may be your HTML style is over-riding it. You might want to try moving the style from your html to the css file. Especially the style for any of your <a> tags.

Comment: Turns out that was it!! Thank you very much, you have no idea how much you helped me :)

Comment: @MonseMunoz glad I could help. Please use the green check to mark this as your answer if this solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding a class to you're a element. Then use that class inside of the CSS, and try from there. If that does not work, then you might try using transition.

```css
.a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: 0.256s;
}

.a:hover {
  transition: 0.256s;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="a">Test</a>
```

Comment: I tried both and it's still not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Another issue I have found in your code, is many of your closing tags, are showing errors of not having any opening tag. You may have messed up your tr and td's somewhere, causing the error.  This might be hindering the css from working.

Answer (score 0):

The inline style style="color: black;..." is stronger than non-inline styles, so you cannot override it.

You should stylize the a tag with a selector (class or tag one).